# std::unique_lock - Создается постоянно в цикле?

Tags: c++

А вот такой вопрос - для блокировки потока используется  std::unique_lock, но, как я понял он создается именно в функции, которую нужно блокировать.
И тут, как бы не совсем понятно, вот к примеру  создал поток, сразу усыпил его, потом разбудил, поток выполнил работу, НО функцию не завершается, функция зациклена, и после выполнения одного цикла идет второй, но на втором круге цикла опять встречается строка:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);
```

И получается, что std::unique_lock - создается постоянно в цикле ? Я имею ввиду не цикл while, а "цикл" goto. Когда код возвращается к метке repeat: и к строке   std::unique_lock - получается опять создается новый объект  std::unique_lock ?

Вот пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable
#include <vector>

std::mutex my_mutex;
std::condition_variable my_cond_var;
int global_status;






void waiting_threads(int id)
{
repeat:

    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);  //Получается он постоянно создается в цикле ?

         while (global_status == 0)
         {
            my_cond_var.wait(my_lock);
         }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------


    std::cout << "thread_id:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ":" << id << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));   //Какая то работа потока.

goto repeat;

}



void go_1()
{
    global_status = 1;
    my_cond_var.notify_one(); 
}


void go_2()
{
    global_status = 0;
}



void go_3()
{
global_status = 1;
my_cond_var.notify_one(); 
}


int main()
{
    global_status=0;


    int kol_vo_thread = 4;                   //Условное кол-во ядер.


    std::vector<std::thread> my_thread_vec;
    my_thread_vec.resize(kol_vo_thread);


//-----------------------------------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < kol_vo_thread; i++)
    {
        my_thread_vec[i] = std::thread(waiting_threads, i);
    }
//-----------------------------------------------------




    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));            
    go_1();   //Пробуждаем поток.

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));  
    go_2();  //Потом усыпляем его.

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); 
    go_3();  //И опять, когда нужно пробуждаем.


    //------------------------------------------------ 
    for (int i = 0; i < kol_vo_thread; i++)
    {
        my_thread_vec[i].join();
    }
    //------------------------------------------------

}
```

Comment: В приличных местах за применение goto можно схлопотать канделябром. Можно легко получить код, который невозможно ни рефакторить не отлаживать

Comment: @gbg, это спорно. Но так или иначе - это к вопросу не относится :)

Comment: Объект `my_lock` **автоматически уничтожается** (с освобождением `my_mutex`) **при выходе из {...}** (он объявлен внутри блока из фигурных скобок). Да, после `goto repeat` он будет снова создан.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, вас ввело в заблуждение название `unique_lock`. Дело в том, что он не "блокирует" функцию, он захватывает мьютекс. Захват мьютекса приводит к тому, что ваша функция засыпает только, если этот же мьютекс захвачен другим потоком, и как только другой поток "отпустит" мьютекс, текущий проснется и получит мьютекс захваченным. Используется для захвата мьютекса объект `unique_lock` в качестве RAII обертки - как только время жизни этого объекта закончится, он автоматически "отпустит" мьютекс.

Теперь, почему этот объект создается снова и снова. Логика работы обычно такова:

- захватываем мьютекс
- проверяем условие, есть ли работа (если нет засыпаем на condition_variable)
- забираем данные с которыми нужно работать
- отпускаем мьютекс
- производим работу
- повторить

Как видим, для нормальной работы этой функции нужно постоянно захватывать и отпускать мьютекс, поэтому локальный `unique_lock` создается и уничтожается

Comment: Спасибо! А почему его нельзя создать глобально и использовать точно так же, но чтобы он не создавался и не уничтожался постоянно. Ведь на создание и уничтожение тратится время. Я пробивал создать глобально, но в функции он не виден.

Comment: Вам стоит почитать, что такое RAII. На самом деле объект `std::unique_lock` очень легкий - у него кроме конструктора и деструктора ничего нет. Контруктор захватывает мьютекс, деструктор отпускает. Практически тоже самое, что вы просто вызовете lock/unlock на мьютексе вручную. Но разница с этим в том, что компилятор отслеживает время жизни объекта и удалит его в любом случае. А если вы отпускаете вручную, то нужно отслеживать, например не вызвать `return` перед этим, ловить исключение итд

Comment: возможно я не правильно понимаю, но тут - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/   - сказано, что - "Objects of type condition_variable always use unique_lock<mutex> to wait".  То есть я не могу использовать просто std::mutex или std::lock_guard.

Comment: @Optimus1 да, я немного подзабыл. `std::lock_guard` еще более легковесный, но не может быть использован с `std::condition_variable`, `std::unique_lock` немного тяжелее, у него есть доп функциональность (его можно вручную разлочить), но цена там невысокая, скорее всего просто дополнительный флаг `bool`. Но если вам просто нужно заблокировать мьютекс без ожидания, то лучше использовать `std::lock_guard`

Answer (score 3):

Это классический паттерн. в строке

```
my_cond_var.wait(my_lock);
```

не просто происходит ожидание. Внутри функции wait вначале происходит разблокирование мютекса, а при выходе с нее - блокируется назад. К сожалению, иногда эта функция может проснуться "случайно" и для этого как раз и нужен внешний while.

в строке

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);
```

мютекс блокируется, но my_lock запоминает его и при выходе с области видимости автоматически разблоирует

То есть, на самом деле вся эта функция выглядит так

```
void waiting_threads(int id)
{
repeat:

    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);  //заблокировали моютекс

         while (global_status == 0)
         {
            my_cond_var.wait(my_lock);
            // разблокировали мютекс
            // ОС не ставит поток в очередь на работу, пока кто то не разбудит
            // если разбудили, лочим мютекс и выходим
         }
     // а вот тут мютекс снова разблокируется.
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------


    std::cout << "thread_id:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ":" << id << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));   //Какая то работа потока.

goto repeat; // Дейкстра был бы в шоке

}
```

**Update**

Ручной вариан:

```cpp
std::condition_variable_any my_cond_var;

void waiting_threads(int id)
{
repeat:

    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    {
         my_mutex.lock();// лочим

         while (global_status == 0)
         {
            my_cond_var.wait(my_mutex);
         }
         my_mutex.unlock();//  разлочим
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------


    std::cout << "thread_id:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ":" << id << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));   //Какая то работа потока.

goto repeat;

}
```

Comment: я имел ввиду другое. Я имел ввиду не цикл While, а "цикл" goto. Когда код возвращается к метке repeat: и к строке   std::unique_lock - получается опять создается новый объект  std::unique_lock ?

Comment: да, создается. Но я бы сказал, что он "супер легкий". Но если Вам это "мешает", можно вручную лочить при входе и разлочивать при выходе. Но я бы так не делал

Comment: а чем вручную лочить ?

Comment: my_mutex.lock()/my_mutex.unlock(), но смысла в этом мало

Comment: простой мьютекс вроде с condition_variable не работает.

Comment: А у Вас там как раз и есть простой мютекс.

Comment: возможно я не правильно понимаю, но тут - cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable - сказано, что - "Objects of type condition_variable always use unique_lock<mutex> to wait". То есть я не могу использовать просто std::mutex или std::lock_guard.

Comment: Если переводить дословно, то это значит что функция wait внутри себя использует такой механизм

Comment: ну то есть вручную лочить не получится.

Comment: @Optimus1 ну почему не получится, можно создать `std::unqie_lock` до цикла и лочить/разлочивать вручную. Просто это смысла не имеет, создание легковесного объекта на стеке - операция быстрая. Усложнение программы и потенциальные ошибки этого не стоят. Не стоит заниматься микрооптимизациями просто так, не зря есть цитата про источник всех зол.

Comment: Несколько комментариев подряд пытаешься показать, что все можно, и все равно получаешь "получается нельзя"

Comment: @KoVadim, покажите пожалуйста, как использовать my_mutex.lock()/my_mutex.unlock() за место unique_lock<mutex> совместно с condition_variable. Я так и не понял, как это возможно из Ваших комментариев.

Comment: Обновил ответ.....

Comment: @KoVadim, а теперь скомпилируйте пожалуйста.

Comment: С телефона очень сложно это сделать. Там нужно ещё использовать std::condition_variable_any вместо std::condition_variable

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо! std::condition_variable_any - работает с std::mutex.